# how can i use the same number for all the calculations

Tags: java, math, calculator

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the numbers only ");
        Scanner num =new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of times you want to run loop ");  
        Scanner loop =new Scanner(System.in);
        int n =loop.nextInt();
        while(n!=0)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the Cases  1 for addition,2 for Subtraction,3 for Division 4 for multipication and 5 for reaminder  ");   
            Scanner cas =new Scanner(System.in);
            int c = cas.nextInt();
            double calc,first,second;
            switch (c)
            {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("addition of two number is ");
                first = num.nextDouble(); 
                second=num.nextDouble();
                calc = first + second;
                System.out.println(calc);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("subtraction of two number is ");
                first = num.nextDouble(); 
                second = num.nextDouble();
                calc = first - second;      
                System.out.println(calc);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("division of two number is ");
                first = num.nextDouble(); 
                second = num.nextDouble();
                calc = first / second;
                System.out.println(calc);
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("multipication of two number is ");
                first = num.nextDouble(); 
                second = num.nextDouble();
                calc = first * second;
                System.out.println(calc);
                break;  
            case 5:
                System.out.println("remainder of two number is ");
                first = num.nextDouble(); 
                second = num.nextDouble();
                calc = first % second;
                System.out.println(calc);
                break;  
            default:
                System.out.println("you did not enter 1,2,3,4,5 you entered something else ");
            }
        n--;
        }
        System.out.println("the program has end, THANK YOU!!"); 
    }
}
```

This the java code for calculation by asking user for input. How can i use the same number for all the calculations in this code?it ask user every time for the new number but i want this code to do all the calculation by only one input.

Comment: learn about static keyword

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the

```
 first = num.nextDouble(); 
 second = num.nextDouble();
```

only once. Call it where you want the user to enter the numbers.

For your example, you should change it to this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the numbers only ");
        Scanner num =new Scanner(System.in);
        double first,second;
        first = num.nextDouble();  //Get first number
        second = num.nextDouble(); //Get second number
        System.out.println("Enter the number of times you want to run loop     ");  
        Scanner loop =new Scanner(System.in);
        int n =loop.nextInt();
        while(n!=0)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the Cases  1 for addition,2 for     Subtraction,3 for Division 4 for multipication and 5 for reaminder  ");   
            Scanner cas =new Scanner(System.in);
            int c = cas.nextInt();
            double calc;
            switch (c)
            {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("addition of two number is ");
                calc = first + second;
                System.out.println(calc);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("subtraction of two number is ");
                calc = first - second;      
                System.out.println(calc);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("division of two number is ");
                calc = first / second;
                System.out.println(calc);
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("multipication of two number is ");
                calc = first * second;
                System.out.println(calc);
                break;  
            case 5:
                System.out.println("remainder of two number is ");
                calc = first % second;
                System.out.println(calc);
                break;  
            default:
                System.out.println("you did not enter 1,2,3,4,5 you entered     something else ");
            }
        n--;
        }
        System.out.println("the program has end, THANK YOU!!"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove

> break;

from every case it will do every case starting from the one the user chose

Is this what you wanted ?

Comment: no i want to decide what calculation it should do by myself but it should take the same numbers for every case  i hit the case number. For Example :     when i enter two numbers the same number should do the calculation for every case